# pig latin equivalent for $cut -c16-19 <filename>

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have following input record : 
0029029070999991901010106004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0202701N015919999999N0000001N9-00781+99999102001ADDGF108991999999999999999999

No ' or space separated fields. Columns can be identified using position. Like year 1901 is column c16-c19. Unix/Linux I use cut -c16-19 filename.

How to get the same (cut -c16-19 equivalent) in pig latin?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [SUBSTRING function](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#substring). For example:

```
A = LOAD '/user/hue/file.txt' USING PigStorage;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE SUBSTRING($0, 15, 19);
DUMP B;

Result
(1901)
```